# Tagged logging is failing in rails 5 while accessing session params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I recently updated app from rails 4 to 5, I had modified some of the middleware configurations to get better logs, this worked fine in rails 4, but after updating to rails, this broke my app caused issues in sending SET-COOKIE header, if i remove the configuration changes I made to middleware the app works.

Now I need a way how can I make tagged logging work in rails 5 similar to the way it was in my previous version of app running in rails 4

```
Rails 4 configuration changes

config.middleware.delete "ActionDispatch::Cookies"
config.middleware.delete "ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore"
config.middleware.insert_before Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.insert_before Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore

@offline_logging_path = "/upload/offline_logs"
    config.log_tags = [
      lambda {|req|
        if req.path != @offline_logging_path
          Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L')
        end
      },
      lambda {|req|
        if req.path != @offline_logging_path
          'ip='+'"'+"#{req.remote_ip}"+'"'
        end
      },
      proc { |req|
        if req.path != @offline_logging_path
          'id='+'"'+"#{req.session[:real_id]}"+'"'
        end
      },
      lambda {|req|
        if req.path != @offline_logging_path
          'ua='+'"'+"#{req.user_agent}"+'"'
        end
      }
    ]
```

Rails 5 changes for tagged logging

```
config.log_tags = [ 
  lambda {|req| Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L')},
  :remote_ip,  
  proc { |request| request.session[:real_id] || 'No Token' },  
  lambda {|req| req.user_agent}
]
```

but this change is not working, request.session[:real_id] is breaking, if i remove thos rack middleware changes

Comment: You should compare the order of `rake middleware` between your branches I think